# Interpretation of p-values & reduction of model deviance for factors in anova() vs summary()

Tags: r, regression, logistic, statistical-significance, categorical-data

My data has 3 major inputs: `BLDDAY` (a factor), `BLDMNT` (a factor), and `D_BLD_SER` (days as an integer variable).  The output is whether input variable has any impact on failure.  My model is: `model = glm(FAILED~BLDDAY+BLDMNT+D_BLD_SER, family="binomial", data=data_list)`.  (I used [UCLA's statistics help site's guide to logistic regression in R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm) to build this model.)

Output:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3282  -0.9123  -0.8128   1.4056   2.1053  

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -0.7672583  0.1317132  -5.825 5.70e-09 ***
BLDDAYMonday    -0.1545646  0.0839380  -1.841  0.06556 .  
BLDDAYSaturday  -0.1257976  0.2028259  -0.620  0.53511    
BLDDAYSunday    -0.1183008  0.1868713  -0.633  0.52669    
BLDDAYThursday  -0.2007452  0.0772653  -2.598  0.00937 ** 
BLDDAYTuesday    0.0480453  0.0758603   0.633  0.52651    
BLDDAYWednesday -0.0358585  0.0760027  -0.472  0.63707    
BLDMNTAug        0.3009445  0.1405545   2.141  0.03226 *  
BLDMNTDec        0.5562170  0.1338467   4.156 3.24e-05 ***
BLDMNTFeb        0.3334978  0.2133475   1.563  0.11801    
BLDMNTJan        0.4076504  0.2277978   1.790  0.07353 .  
BLDMNTJul        0.1306585  0.1415302   0.923  0.35591    
BLDMNTJun       -0.0357361  0.1428105  -0.250  0.80241    
BLDMNTMar        0.4570491  0.1949815   2.344  0.01907 *  
BLDMNTMay       -0.2292620  0.1614577  -1.420  0.15562    
BLDMNTNov        0.3060012  0.1334034   2.294  0.02180 *  
BLDMNTOct        0.2390501  0.1341877   1.781  0.07484 .  
BLDMNTSep        0.2481405  0.1384901   1.792  0.07317 .  
D_BLD_SER       -0.0020960  0.0003367  -6.225 4.82e-10 ***

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 10288  on 8182  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10154  on 8164  degrees of freedom
AIC: 10192
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The ANOVA table is the following:

```
anova(model, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table
Model: binomial, link: logit
Response: FAILED
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                       8182      10288              
BLDDAY     6   20.392      8176      10268  0.002357 ** 
BLDMNT    11   70.662      8165      10197 9.142e-11 ***
D_BLD_SER  1   43.797      8164      10154 3.642e-11 ***
```

My questions are:

1. Although the p-values for all three components are less than 0.05, which can be considered as significant, the deviance reduced due to each component is less than 1% of the total deviance. **Normally the interpretation of output like this is input parameter affects output and it's better to use this parameter then using noting.** But does it really make sense of taking this parameter as significant input?
2. The p-values for `BLDDAY` and `BLDMNT` given by `anova()` is the overall p-value,  which is significant, but `summary()` gives detailed impact of each factor level. If I consider the p-values for each factor overall `BLDDAY` is significant but individually only `BLDDAYThursday` is significant. I am bit confused not as whether to consider `BLDDAY` as significant input, or Thursday only, or Thursday & Friday both.